# Mule4 support for TCP connection

Tags: tcp, mule, tcpclient, tcplistener, mule4

I am trying to consume .Net WCF APIs over TCP in Mule4, but couldn't able to find any connector.In Mule3 has seperate TCP connector for receiving and sending messages over TCP.

Can any one please help me guiding on how Mule4 would consume messages over TCP?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent connector for Mule 4 is the [Sockets connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/sockets/sockets-connector).

Comment: Many Thanks aled, let me try exploring it.

Comment: Hi aled, I configured the connector but getting exception ...java.net.SocketException: 

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
at org.mule.extension.socket.api.client.TcpClient.write(TcpClient.java:45)

Comment: That is a different issue than the one described in the original question. Please create a new question with the details of the flow, configurations and errors.